# Flutter XCode Permission Denied

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart, permission-denied

Whenever I run the project I get this error saying permission denied

````
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           37.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/facebook_auth_desktop-0.0.9/lib/src/custom_http_client.dart:3:8: Error: 
Error when reading '../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/http-0.13.6/lib/http.dart': Permission denied

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like that you don't have permission reading `http.dart` file, you can try the following methods:

1. Modify the permissions of the .pub-cache directory to read and write. Run the following command in a terminal:

```bash
sudo chmod -R 777 ~/.pub-cache
```

2. Delete the .pub-cache directory, and then re-run the flutter pub get
   command to re-download dependencies:

```bash
rm -rf ~/.pub-cache
flutter pub get
```

3. Add your Terminal or iTerm2 App to `Full Access` list, if you use these to run flutter app.